# How to work with buttons in an extended movieclip class

Tags: flash, button, actionscript-2

Say I make a class that extends the movieclip class and this class has a number of buttons in it.  This movie clip exists in an .fla and is linked to the class definition.  How can I control the events from within the class?  The following does not work:

```
class newMovie extends MovieClip {
   var test_btn:Button;
   function newMovie() {
   }
   function test_btn.onRelease() {
       trace("Button pressed");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this,

```
import mx.utils.Delegate;
class newMovie extends MovieClip {
    var test_btn:Button;
    function newMovie() {
        test_btn.onRelease = Delegate.create(this, onButtonRelease);
    }
    function onButtonRelease() {
        trace("Button pressed");
    }
}
```